# virtual directory - How to load image files for asp.net viewing?

Tags: asp.net, iis, virtualization

There are so many similar questions around the web, but none of them have helped me with this.

I have an asp.net application on a company intranet server. It is used to access a database on another file server, which also contains a number of images relevant to each record in the database.

I am a developer, but not a network person.  I know a little bit about IIS, and using the IIS Manager, I created a virtual directory inside the asp.net application folder that maps to the UNC address on the other server where the images are. Using IIS Manager, I can explore the virtual directory and see all the files there. The problem is getting them to show up in my asp.net application.

I've tried setting permissions on the folder for Network Service, IUSR_aspnetserver, and my own credentials; I've tried various permutations of the path string, with / or // or \ or \, etc. I've tried impersonation, but I don't know if I am doing it right. I've placed a "debug" label on the page that tells me the path of the image while the app is running, and it is correct. Nothing seems to work.

Obviously there's something I am missing, but my network comprehension is around zero, my IIS experience is hardly any better, and I can't seem to get our staff of IT "experts" to help. And before you jump to any conclusions, I have a great personality.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT for @MohsinMehmood:

(I hope this is not too convoluted)

The page has a mapped drive in IIS to UNC share `\\OtherServer\AppName\Images` to a folder named ReceiptImages.

The web.config file has this entry:

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="ImageFilePath" value="ReceiptImages/"/>
 </appSettings>
```

And in the PageLoad event I have

```
 ViewState("ImagesPath") = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ImageFilePath")
```

To create a global path string.

Then in code (VB) it's:

```
Dim btnReceiptThumbnailButton As New ImageButton
      With btnReceiptThumbnailButton
           .ID = "btn" & LineItem
           .CssClass = "thumbnails"
           .ImageAlign = ImageAlign.AbsMiddle
           .Visible = True
           .BackColor = Drawing.Color.White
           .BorderColor = Drawing.Color.Black
           .BorderWidth = 1
           .ImageUrl = ViewState("ImagesPath") & LineItem
           .CommandName = "GetReceiptImage"
           .CommandArgument = LineItem

           End With
```

I don't know if it was important enough to mention that the image is being placed in a button control to make it a thumbnail.

Comment: Check your asp.net website application pool settings and determine identity. If it is ApplicationPoolIdentity, try changing the permissions of your network directory to application pool identity user which has naming format like `IIS AppPool\{AppPoolName}` e.g. `IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool` for `DefaultAppPool`

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I hadn't mentioned it, but I did check the app pool, and it's set for network service. I changed it to ApplicationPoolIdentity and that shut down the whole site. I also tried creating an app pool identity with my login credentials, and that also shut down the whole site. I had to switch back to network service just to get the site back up again.

Comment: Ok! Have you tried giving `NetworkService` user read permission to image directrory?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood Oh, yeah. It shows to have *all* of the permissions checked. One thing I don't understand is that the check marks are greyed out, making them  unchangeable. Not being an IT person, I don't know what that means.

Comment: Can you share code how you are trying to reference images from virtual directory in your asp.net application?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I've added it to my original post.

Comment: I am assuming that `ReceiptImages` is the name of virtual directory and `LineItem`  is image path relative to `ReceiptImages`. So in web.config try changing it to `/ReceiptImages/` (add slash before). If image is still broken, inspect the rendered html using browser Developer tools to check the image path

Comment: It still failed. The path as shown by the "debug" label was ` /ReceiptImages/image-5188-2147935059-20180628152808-00.jpg`

Comment: Have you verified that image exists at the root of the images folder? Also, what happens if you paste the url in browser e.g. `http://yourwebsitedomain/ReceiptImages/image-5188-2147935059-20180628152808-00.jpg`?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I did try that. I made an HTML page with the img tag: <img src="receiptimages\image-4248-4325579434-20180507170258-00.jpg" /> And it didn't work. On the same page I made another img tag referencing another image in the local directory (not the virtual directory), and it works.

Comment: So what you can try is that select virtual directory in IIS and then click on `Basic Settings` and then click on `Connect As` button to see which user is selected. Change that to some user in admin group who has read permissions on that network folder.  What happens when you try `http://yourwebsitedomain/ReceiptImages/image-5188-2147935059-20180628152808-00.jpg`?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood Well that didn't work either. I used my own credentials, and I am an admin for that server. I will need to defer this discussion until tomorrow because it's quitting time and I have to be someplace after work. I appreciate your help!